# Can a browser override css specifications?

Tags: css, class, browser

I'am currently working on a website that is using the wordPress content managment system and i was trying to get rid of some inline style definitions for some inputs that i wanted to put into the css file.

I copied the exact inline style definition into the stylesheet in a class that targets input (i.e input.className, ClassName having the same elements as the inline style definition) and then added said class to the input.

What happened is the button was rendered with the browser's default appearance settings instead of the ones i defined in a class.

I did some testing and ctrl+f in the css file to see if there we're any more specific css definitions for inputs but there we're none.

Then i copied the whole css into a file and i created a quick html pointing to that local stylesheet, putting just an input with my newly create class on the page to see if it had anything to do with wordpress.

On my local machine the class is applied to the button, but on wordpress it does nothing.

Does anybody know where does the problem comes from or can anybody suggest some possible hints into where i should look.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you used Firebug or Fiddler or something similar to verify that the external CSS file is actually being loaded? Sounds to me like you might have the wrong path to the file.

Answer (score 2):

If the code works outside of Wordpress but doesn't work inside of Wordpress, what led you to the conclusion that the problem lies with the *browser* overriding something?  Isn't it infinitely more likely that something *Wordpress* is doing is causing the issue?

Inline styles have high [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).  By moving the CSS rules to an external stylesheet, you lowered its specificity.  It's likely that Wordpress' CSS includes rules that conflict with yours, and have a lower specificity than your inline styles, but a higher specificity than the same rules moved to an external stylesheet.

To fix this you need to raise your rules' specificities.  The quick hack fix for this is to use `!important`, but you should really figure out what you are conflicting with and address it by tailoring your CSS to match.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question title, yes browsers can override CSS but only if you wittingly installed a plugin/extension to do so (eg facebook themes), but **by default the browser does not do so.**

You could check if your Wordpress install or browsers has cached the page (you can delete/remove the cache to do so), I know this is an issue while editing PHPBB themes while live, but I suggest go all out, create a separate CSS file and new unique class name in it (avoid any confliction) and double check to be absolutely sure